# How can I access the US Google page and doodle from abroad?

Tags: google-doodle

I am located in Israel, and would like to access the American Google home page and "Doodle". Even when I choose the "google.com" option on the google.co.il page, the US page it takes me to does not display any of the "doodles" currently on display in the US. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The main US google page that bypasses "No Country Redirect" is available at http://google.com/ncr

Comment: I've tried that - but it still doesn't show up...